# moving files recurisively on linux

Tags: linux, find, xargs

`find ./dir -type f -iname "*.t[argz]*[bz2]" -print | xargs mv --target-directory=dir`
seems to fail on file that has spaces in the name. 
how to improve it? or alternative?

thanks for answer below: my mv doesn't support --null or -0, I'm using cygwin:

```
$ mv --help
Usage: mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

Mandatory arguments t
.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-print0` instead of `-print` on the `find` command, and the xargs `-0` (or `--null`) option - then NULs will be used as separators rather than newlines and spaces.

```
find ./dir -type f -iname "*.t[argz]*[bz2]" -print0 | xargs --null mv --target-directory=dir
```

Comment: $ find ./ -type f -iname "*.xls" -print0 | xargs mv --null --target-directory=x
ls
xargs: Warning: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed thro
ugh in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?
mv: unrecognized option `--null'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Sorry - should have been an xargs option, not a mv option!  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the -exec option for find?

```
find ./dir -type f -iname "*.t[argz][bz2]" -exec mv {} --target-directory=dir ';'
```

The -exec option will execute any options following it as a command until it sees the semi-colon wrapped in quotes.  This way you won't have to deal with the spacing issue.

Comment: This spawns a subprocess for every file, though, where the xargs variant batches hundreds of files up onto the same command line.  For small operations like a single mv invocation, that can be a significant performance difference.   Though you have to use -print0 and --null as martin points out above unless you're absolutely sure the filenames have no whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

GNU find

```
find ./dir -type f -iname "*.t[argz]*[bz2]" -exec mv "{}" /destination +;
```